receive_sharing_intent not working in iOS sharing from phone to flutter app
In my Flutter app I am trying to share a file to my app. In Android, it works perfectly but in iOS, it's showing the options to share but the app is not opening. I am using receving_sharing_intent. I have added all necessary filed to iOS dev acc. I am attaching some of my code below.
Attached image:

Here is the code:
main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:receive_sharing_intent/receive_sharing_intent.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late StreamSubscription _intentSub;
  final _sharedFiles = <SharedMediaFile>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Listen to media sharing coming from outside the app while the app is in the memory.
    _intentSub = ReceiveSharingIntent.instance.getMediaStream().listen((value) {
      setState(() {
        _sharedFiles.clear();
        _sharedFiles.addAll(value);

        print(_sharedFiles.map((f) => f.toMap()));
      });
    }, onError: (err) {
      print("getIntentDataStream error: $err");
    });

    // Get the media sharing coming from outside the app while the app is closed.
    ReceiveSharingIntent.instance.getInitialMedia().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _sharedFiles.clear();
        _sharedFiles.addAll(value);
        print(_sharedFiles.map((f) => f.toMap()));

        // Tell the library that we are done processing the intent.
        ReceiveSharingIntent.instance.reset();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _intentSub.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const textStyleBold = const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Shared files:", style: textStyleBold),
              Text(_sharedFiles
                  .map((f) => f.toMap())
                  .join(",\n****************\n")),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Runner/info.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AppGroupId</key>
    <string>$(CUSTOM_GROUP_ID)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>RSI Example</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>AppGroupId</key>
    <string>$(CUSTOM_GROUP_ID)</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                <string>Editor</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>ShareMedia-$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>To upload photos, please allow permission to access your photo library.</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>


AppDelegates.swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import receive_sharing_intent

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    
    // If the application is using multiple libraries, which needs to implement this function here in AppDelegate, you should check if the url is made from SwiftReceiveSharingIntentPlugin (if so, return the sharingIntent response) or call the handler of specific librabry
    override func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        let sharingIntent = SwiftReceiveSharingIntentPlugin.instance
        if sharingIntent.hasMatchingSchemePrefix(url: url) {
            return sharingIntent.application(app, open: url, options: options)
        }
        
         // For example load MSALPublicClientApplication
         // return MSALPublicClientApplication.handleMSALResponse(url, sourceApplication: options[.sourceApplication] as? String)

         // Cancel url handling
         // return false

         // Proceed url handling for other Flutter libraries like uni_links
         return super.application(app, open: url, options:options)
    }
}


ShareViewController.swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import receive_sharing_intent

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    
    // If the application is using multiple libraries, which needs to implement this function here in AppDelegate, you should check if the url is made from SwiftReceiveSharingIntentPlugin (if so, return the sharingIntent response) or call the handler of specific librabry
    override func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        let sharingIntent = SwiftReceiveSharingIntentPlugin.instance
        if sharingIntent.hasMatchingSchemePrefix(url: url) {
            return sharingIntent.application(app, open: url, options: options)
        }
        
         // For example load MSALPublicClientApplication
         // return MSALPublicClientApplication.handleMSALResponse(url, sourceApplication: options[.sourceApplication] as? String)

         // Cancel url handling
         // return false

         // Proceed url handling for other Flutter libraries like uni_links
         return super.application(app, open: url, options:options)
    }
}


Share Extension/info.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AppGroupId</key>
        <string>$(CUSTOM_GROUP_ID)</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
        <key>NSExtension</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
            <dict>
                <key>PHSupportedMediaTypes</key>
                   <array>
                       <string>Video</string>
                       <string>Image</string>
                   </array>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
                    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                    <integer>100</integer>
                    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
                    <integer>100</integer>
                    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
            <string>MainInterface</string>
            <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>



I have the same issue. also (I believe your ShareViewController.swift) it shouldn't be the same as the AppDelegates.

I've found an alternative to receive_sharing_intent. It's called share_handler
The configuration is mostly the same at receive_sharing_intent, except that instead of naming the extension "Share Extension" it should be "ShareExtension".
ShareViewController is also different:
import share_handler_ios_models
    
class ShareViewController: ShareHandlerIosViewController {}

